# Geofence didExitRegion is never called

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, geofencing

I'm trying to implement Geofencing into an app I'm working on. currently, I'm unable to pass the
desired output to the console because `didExitRegion` is never called.

What might be the cause of this and how may I go about solving it?

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()


    func setupManager() {

        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        //locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

        // Set Geofencing region
        let geofencingRegion: CLCircularRegion = CLCircularRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(30.510074, 114.330510), radius: 100, identifier: "Wuhan")
        geofencingRegion.notifyOnExit = true
        geofencingRegion.notifyOnEntry = true

        // Start monitoring
        locationManager.startMonitoring(for: geofencingRegion)
    }



    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        setupManager()
        let mapView = MKMapView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        mapView.userTrackingMode = .follow
        return mapView
        
    }


    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) {
    }
}

class MapAppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var locationManager: CLLocationManager?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        self.locationManager!.delegate = self

        return true
    }
}

extension MapAppDelegate{

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
        print("Hello World")
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
        print("Welcome Home")
    }
}
```

The output I'm getting is multiple iterations of

```
2020-12-11 18:41:29.916937+0800 Geofencing[4225:235542] [VKDefault] Style Z is requested for an invisible rect
```

I want to create a state to check whether the user has entered the area or left the area to pull other view controllers on my MainView so I'm starting here.

Comment: Hello @LittleTim, I am having the same console error, did you find a solution for that, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason `didExitRegion` is never called is that you are not setting the `CLLocationManager` delegate.

In `MapView` you are creating an instance of `CLLocationManager` and then calling `.startMonitoring` on this instance. But you never set the delegate on this instance.

True, you are setting the delegate on the instance you created in your `MapAppDelegate`, but that is not the instance on which you are calling `.startMonitoring`.

You should refactor your code in such a way that you only create a single instance of `CLLocationManager`, and be sure to set the delegate on that instance.